# Is "boggles down" an idiom of "simplifies"?

Tags: etymology, idioms

I feel comfortable with the phrase *boggles down* as a synonym for *simplifies*, but I was surprised to not find a dictionary entry of this use.

Here's an example:

> If your "use case" boggles down to avoiding assigning a variable, that seems like a really minor discomfort.

I'm looking for a little validation that this is in fact a common idiom and I'm interested in where it comes from. At idioms.freedictionary.com I see an entry for [boggles](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/boggles), but it means something totally different ("to confuse") without the *down* modifier.

Comment: Never heard of _boggle down_, what you describe however sounds a lot like _boil down._ Which is in dictionaries, e.g. [here](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/boil-down-to#boil-down-to__1)

Comment: I've heard "bogged down" for someone being swamped with too much to do, but never "boggles down."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better choice here would be to use *boil down*, which basically means "to simplify" or "to extract the essence". *Boggles down* doesn't appear to be popular, according to Google results.

***Boil down to (something)*** — [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/boil-down-to-sth)

> If a situation or problem boils down to something, that is the main reason for it.
>   *"The problem boils down to one thing - lack of money."*

Comment: *Boil down* does not (necessarily) mean *simplify*. It means *extract the essence*.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Agreed, but I merely boiled down the definition to "simplify".